# Hashing Issue, Non-Text Files

Tags: python, hash

My code works ok except for hashing.  It works fine on hashing text files but as soon as it encounters a jpg or other file type, it crashes.  I know it's some type of encoding error, but I'm stumped on how to encode it properly for non-text files.

```
#import libraries
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import hashlib
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from pathlib import Path
import glob

#user input
path = input ("Please enter directory: ")

print ("===============================================")

#processing input
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("Processing directory: ", (path))
else:
    print("Invalid directory.")
    logging.basicConfig(filename="error.log", level=logging.ERROR)
    logging.error(' The directory is not valid, please run the script again with the correct directory.')

print ("===============================================")

#process directory
directory = Path(path)
paths = []
filename = []
size = []
hashes = []
modified = []
files = list(directory.glob('**/*.*'))

for file in files:
    paths.append(file.parents[0])
    filename.append(file.parts[-1])
    size.append(file.stat().st_size)
    modified.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(file.stat().st_mtime))
    with open(file) as f:        
        hashes.append(hashlib.md5(f.read().encode()).hexdigest())

#output in to tablecx
report = PrettyTable()

column_names = ['Path', 'File Name', 'File Size', 'Last Modified Time', 'MD5 Hash']
report.add_column(column_names[0], paths)
report.add_column(column_names[1], filename)
report.add_column(column_names[2], size)   
report.add_column(column_names[3], modified)
report.add_column(column_names[4], hashes)
report.sortby = 'File Size'

print(report)
```

Comment: You're making us guess what the error is and where it happens.  Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

change following lines

```
    with open(file) as f:        
        hashes.append(hashlib.md5(f.read().encode()).hexdigest())
```

to

```
    with open(file, "rb") as f:        
        hashes.append(hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest())
```

Doing this you will read the contents directly as bytes and you calculate the hash.

Your version tried to read the file as text and re-encoded it to bytes. 
Reading a file as text means, the code tries to decode it with the system's encoding. For some byte combinations this will fail, as they are no valid code points for the given encoding.

So just read everything directly as bytes.

Comment: Thank you @gelonida!  A simple solution, but it would have taken me forever to figure it out.